# Rails: Getting missing template error, but the template is there

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm using the jquery fullcalendar, and gave it events: '/calendar/1' to call the events feed.  I have the following in my routes:

```
match 'calendar/:id' => 'schedules#calendar_feed'
```

If I type into the address bar 
`http://localhost:3000/calendar/1?start=1310886000&end=1311490800&_=1311385591892`
it loads the page.  If I try to load the page and let fullcalendar call the url it returns the error:

```
<p>Missing template schedules/calendar_feed with {:handlers=&gt;[:erb, :rjs, :builder, :rhtml, :rxml], :formats=&gt;[:xml], :locale=&gt;[:en, :en]} in view paths 
&quot;/Users/lukeconner/Dropbox/CFAdmin/app/views&quot;,
&quot;/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/kaminari-0.12.4/app/views&quot;, 
&quot;/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/devise-1.3.4/app/views&quot;</p>
```

I've tried calendar_feed.xml.builder, calendar_feed.js.erb, calendar_feed.html.erb and no matter what I name the view file it returns the error.

Comment: What is the full path of this view?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, the url I included is the actual URL that the calendar feed calls, and the route shows the actual controller and view action.

Comment: Have you run `rake routes`? What happens if you visit `localhost:3000/calendar/1`?

Comment: I put that in the question, if I type in the url the page displays, it's only when the calendar function tries to call it that it fails and gives the error about the missing template.

Comment: @Jhorra: I meant the actual template path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is most likely your calendar plugin is asking for a js response. If you can check your logs you will see something like this:

```
Started GET "/calendar" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-07-04 00:46:56 +0800
Processing by SchedulesController#calendar_feed as *JS*
```

or something else. If it IS JS, then all you need to do is to tell your app to render a json string or something like this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js { #your calendar's expected response }
end
```

Comment: That's exactly what it was, I had the controller set up to handle xml and it was calling with js.

Comment: yeah i usually fell victim for that a couple of months ago haha